# Meteor HTTP.post to Plaid returning 401

Tags: meteor, plaid

I've been trying to do an HTTP.post with data, but I keep getting a 401 response saying that one of the vars (client_id) is missing.

Code:

```
fetchPlaidAccounts: function (options) {
    this.unblock();
    response = HTTP.post(config.plaid.base_url + 'connect', {
        data: {
            client_id: config.plaid.client_id,
            secret: config.plaid.secret,
            username: options.username,
            password: options.password,
            type: options.institution,
            email: options.email,
            options: '{"login_only":true,"list":true}'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

I did a HTTP.get earlier and that worked just fine using params instead of data.

I also console.log’d all the variables, and they all have values.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question.

Come to find out, I don't need to add `headers` when it's in the server side.  Those headers should only be needed when you're running calls on the client side.

So, the final call looks like this:

```
fetchPlaidAccounts: function (options) {
    this.unblock();
    var d = {
        client_id: config.plaid.client_id,
        secret   : config.plaid.secret,
        username : options.username,
        password : options.password,
        email    : options.email,
        type     : options.institution,
        options: '{"login_only":true,"list":true}'
    };
    var response = HTTP.post(config.plaid.base_url + 'connect', { data: d });
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `params` instead of data:

```
HTTP.post(config.plaid.base_url + 'connect', {
    params: {
        ...
    }
```

`data` sends the values as JSON encoded as the body during the POST. Params sends them as multi/part form data, which is what I suspect the API uses.

Comment: Unfortunately that response with a 404

`Error: failed [404] {   "code": 1601,   "message": "product not available",   "resolve": "This product is not yet available for this institution." }`

Comment: @nateritter It might worth be checking out the API with `curl`. If you got that error it means its an issue with your input data and not the code.

Comment: I did that, and it worked under curl, but I finally figured out the issue. Will post the answer.  Thanks for the help @Akshat.